# Start OpenVPN through intent from another APP

Tags: android, android-intent, openvpn

Hello fellow Stackoverflowers,

a few days ago I found this neat little function to start and connect OpenVPN from another app using intents.

```
    private void startVPN(){
    Intent openVPN = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
    openVPN.setPackage("net.openvpn.openvpn");
    openVPN.setClassName("net.openvpn.openvpn", "net.openvpn.openvpn.OpenVpnClient");
    openVPN.putExtra("net.openvpn.openvpn.AUTOSTART_PROFILE_NAME","10.10.10.10 [10.10.10.10]");
    startActivityForResult(openVPN,0);

}
```

Now my question is:

Do I only need to have OpenVPN (connect or for android) installed or do I need to create something like a .jar libary to use it?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `startActivity`, therefore you will need whatever app that includes that `net.openvpn.openvpn` package and `Intent` filter.

`setClassName` is calling into that package for a particular class that will ultimately take some `Intent` extras.

So no JAR file, yes to needing the app installed. If you don't have the app installed, I think the `onActivityResult` will come back with other than `OK` response code.

Answer (score 0):

the intent you created only opens openVpn application and for that the openVpn application should be installed on the device or this code will crash.you can check if the intent will resolved by this code

```
 // Verify that the intent will resolve to an activity
 if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
      startActivity(sendIntent);
}
```